# UFW blocks packets by the router, spams the log

Tags: ufw

While checking my systems logs I noticed this:

```
Dec 30 19:45:24 Nick-Laptop kernel: [ 5324.288321] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:00:05:59:49:62:aa:08:00 SRC=192.168.2.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x18 PREC=0xA0 TTL=1 ID=1000 PROTO=2
```

My point is is that just a packet comming from the internet thats blocked or a packet comming from my router. Why is it being blocked? Can I get more information about the packet? Can I prevent the logs from happening?

My ufw rules:

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing)
New profiles: skip
```

Comment: The packet is most likely coming from a source on your LAN, possibly your router. See [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address) that explains the Multicast Addresses used for services.

Comment: So?  It's doing what you told it to.

Comment: @psusi still its spamming the logs its like 1 packet per 10 seconds.

Comment: @Nick, so?  What's your question?

Comment: @psusi well where its comming from, why is it being blocked and if theres a way to stop the spam of that line.

Comment: It's coming from a computer on your lan and it's being blocked because you set ufw to block all incoming connections.  It sounds like you are playing with things you don't understand for no reason, so my advice is to remove ufw and forget about it.

Comment: In any case: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 2):

You are denying all incoming packets from `192.168.2.1`. UFW is just informing you that it's blocking the packet. You should either add a rule that allows the packet, or turn off the logging (not recommended) or just don't use UFW unless you are clear about what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

To allow all addresses on 192.168.2.x, add this rule:

```
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.2.0/24
```

To allow all addresses on 192.168.x.x, add this rule:

```
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.0.0/16
```

To learn more, see:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW
- [UFW - allow range of IP addresees?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/646424/ufw-allow-range-of-ip-addresees)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing#IPv4_CIDR_blocks