# UFW - allow range of IP addresees?

Tags: networking, configuration, firewall, ufw

I can add a rule using UFW firewall to allow a single known IP `192.168.1.32` to access my test webserver (`192.168.1.48` (on a local mostly trusted network) on Ubuntu 14.04 using:

```
sudo ufw allow proto tcp from 192.168.1.23 to 192.168.1.48 port 80
```

Is there a way I can add a range of addressees *(e.g. `192.168.1.30-192.168.1.50` to allow more machines on my current network)*? Using `192.168.1.30-192.168.1.50` and `192.168.1.30-192.168.1.50` don't work and results in `ERROR: Bad source address`.

Comment: For 14 hosts  (192.168.1.17 to 192.168.1.30) 192.168.1.23/28, For 30 hosts 192.168.1.0/27 (192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.30) but nothing for 20 hosts.

Comment: Where did the previous comments go? The text of the question does not agree with the example ufw line. (?) @A.B. a mask of 28 bits would allow 16 host addresses through and a mask of 27 bits would allow 32 host addresses through. Wouldn't it? Disclaimer: I use iptables and not ufw.

Comment: @Doug If it was my comment I might have removed because I couldn't edit it and copied the wrong info :). Both answers *(which I think were good :(, and I could give screenshots of if needed)* have been deleted though, but [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DizPa.png) is  a screenshot of the thing I think you were replying too

Comment: @A.B. the answer you gave worked (the second command did anyways, the first not at all), the addresses I have were ones I was testing from - the one I think I want access from could be in `192.168.1.10-192.168.1.50` (sorry if not clear, they seem to be assigned pretty randomly... ). I was going to test from other addresses but I think your answer could be the solution. BTW, due to having less than 10k, doug can't see your answer.

Comment: For 192.168.1.10-192.168.1.50 the nearest, but larger, rule would use 192.168.1.0/26 which would be 192.168.1.0-192.168.1.63

Answer (score 16):

You need to use a binary number (2,4,8,16, 32) so either you use a bigger or a smaller range. *Exactly* 20 hosts just is not possible with a bitmask in a single rule:

- 16 hosts (192.168.1.16 to 192.168.1.31):

  ```
  sudo ufw allow proto tcp from  192.168.1.16/28 to 192.168.1.48 port 80
  ```

  Details

  ```
  Address:   192.168.1.16          11000000.10101000.00000001.0001 0000
  Rule Mask: 255.255.255.240 = 28  11111111.11111111.11111111.1111 0000
  Wildcard:  0.0.0.15              00000000.00000000.00000000.0000 1111

  HostMin:   192.168.1.16          11000000.10101000.00000001.0001 0000
  HostMax:   192.168.1.31          11000000.10101000.00000001.0000 1111
  ```
- 32 hosts (192.168.1.0 - 192.168.1.31)

  ```
  sudo ufw allow proto tcp from 192.168.1.0/27 to 192.168.1.48 port 80
  ```

  Details

  ```
  Address:   192.168.1.0           11000000.10101000.00000001.000 00000
  Rule Mask: 255.255.255.224 = 27  11111111.11111111.11111111.111 00000
  Wildcard:  0.0.0.31              00000000.00000000.00000000.000 11111

  HostMin:   192.168.1.0           11000000.10101000.00000001.000 00000
  HostMax:   192.168.1.31          11000000.10101000.00000001.000 11111
  ```
- 64 hosts (192.168.1.0 - 192.168.1.63)

  ```
  sudo ufw allow proto tcp from 192.168.1.0/26 to 192.168.1.48 port 80
  ```

  Details

  ```
  Address:   192.168.1.0           11000000.10101000.00000001.00 000000
  Rule Mask: 255.255.255.192 = 26  11111111.11111111.11111111.11 000000
  Wildcard:  0.0.0.63              00000000.00000000.00000000.00 111111

  HostMin:   192.168.1.0           11000000.10101000.00000001.00 000000
  HostMax:   192.168.1.63          11000000.10101000.00000001.00 111111
  ```

---

*Explanation*

I can't give a better explanation than [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_subnetting_reference)

Comment: Hmmmm.... the second works from IPs 192.168.1.23, 192.168.1.27 and 192.168.1.31, but `192.168.1.0/28` doesn't work with any. What reason is their for constriction on the ranges?

Comment: @Wilf Sorry, I can't give a better explanation than [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_subnetting_reference) :\

Comment: @Wilf Only for 192.168.1.23, 192.168.1.27 and 192.168.1.31?

Comment: You are are not defining a sub-net with a bit mask allow rule for iptables or ufw. A mask of 28 will allow 16 host addresses and a mask of 27 will allow 32 host addresses through. But yes, it does depend on what your real sub-net mask is, and if you hit the boundaries or not. The 28 bit mask example doesn't overlap the desired range at all, it should be `192.168.1.16/28` to cover 192.168.1.16 through 192.168.1.31 inclusive.

Answer (score 9):

**Allow Incoming from Specific IP Address or Subnet**
To allow incoming connections from a specific IP address or subnet, specify the source. For example, run this command:

```
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 22
```

OR

```
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24 to 192.168.1.48 port 80
```

Answer (score 3):

I like this

```
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 22
```

I use ufw all the time, I like the numbering scheme as well which helps me keep track of the packet flow:

```
sudo ufw insert 1 allow in proto tcp from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port
22 comment "SSH Network Connection"
```

Answer (score 2):

pretty old question however if still someone wondering this is a way i found

```
cat geolocationIpList.txt | awk '/^[^#]/ { print $1 }' | sudo xargs -I {} ufw deny from {} to any
```

it read each line from text and update firewall rules

you can change it to allow if want to revert it back...